# Why does the node.js' async behave strange?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, limit

In the example:

```
async.eachLimit([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 6, function(a, b) {
    console.log("current: " + a);
    b("done");
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else { 
      console.log("completely done");
    }
  }
);
```

Output:

```
current: 1
error
current: 2
current: 3
current: 4
current: 5
current: 6
undefined
```

Why such a strange behaviour? Where comes the error and undefined from? And where are the other 4 elements processed? When is the async's callback is called?
As expected from me:

```
current: 1
done
current: 2
done
current: 3
done
current: 4
done
current: 5
done
current: 6
done
current: 7
done
current: 8
done
current: 9
done
current: 10
done
compeletely done
```

So that only 6 elements are active at the same time.

What should I change to get the behaviour of async as I expected?

## Update:

and if I use

```
async.**eachSeries**([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], function(a, b) {
    console.log("current: " + a);
    b("done");
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else { 
      console.log("completely done");
    }
  }
);
```

then the output is weird too:

```
current: 1
error
undefined
```

Comment: You are not printing `done` only `compeletely done` at the end. See Jonathan's answer on why it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the issues stem from this line:

```
b("done");
```

This sets `"done"` as an `err` since [that's what the 1st arguments is](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback):

> The iterator is passed a **`callback(err)`** which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occured, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.

Based on the output you listed as expected, you probably wanted:

```
console.log("done");
b(null); // or: `b()`
```

---

1. *Where comes the error and undefined from?*

   The `error` is from the `callback`:

   ```
   if (err) {
       console.log("error");
   }
   ```

   The `undefined`, however, isn't from the snippet. Though, if you're using Node's interactive REPL, then that would be the source as it'll display `eachLimit`'s `return` value (which is `undefined`).
2. *When is the async's callback is called?*

   When an `err` is passed, the `callback` is called early.
3. *And where are the other 4 elements processed?*

   Once an `err` has been passed, `async` functions will stop iterating. `eachLimit` only makes it to `6` because it chooses to finish the current "*batch*" before stopping.

---

As for `eachLimit()` vs `eachSeries()`, that depends on what the `iterator` does. Currently, the `iterator` is entirely synchronous, so both functions will perform rather similarly -- iterating 1 value at a time.

And, just to be clear: The `async` library can't make synchronous tasks asynchronous. It actually assumes the tasks are already asynchronous and simply helps to manage a group of them.